# Can I open a specific sheet only to repair the corrupted file

Tags: excel

So my file is corrupted and I know the reason by accessing the "extracted value" from file.
Some idiot in my team accidentally copied some value and pasted while making a new row, enlarging the whole table from Column number 20 to 3000+ , making the whole file too large to open.

I tried "open and repair", "open in protected mode" still not able to open the file, showing:
[image: error message]
Is there a way to fix it without having to extract those values and build somewhere else? Since there are linkage with this file with powerBI and stuffs, don't want to bother. thanks so much!

Comment: Do I assume that there is no backup anywhere? on a server or a different machine that is offline and has not updated yet?

Comment: Yes there is no backup anywhere, so there no such version before this change exist in this world....

Comment: try to open it using google sheets or open office. If it was up to me.. opening it in winzip/7z/anyzipManager will be also a solution..